# Fail to crop image with error: failed to compile fragment shader Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to crop the faces from BlazeFaceModel based on the bounding boxes but I am getting the following error. It throws a huge error in my console with a lot of what looks like C++ code. I have not seen this before and am not sure what to do to fix it.

```
    const tensorDims = { height: 224, width: 224, depth: 3 };
    const returnTensors = true;
    const faces = await bfModel
      .estimateFaces(tensor, returnTensors)
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    const tensorReshaped = tensor.reshape([1, 224, 224, 3]);
    const scale = {
      height: styles.camera.height / tensorDims.height,
      width: styles.camera.width / tensorDims.width
    };

    // Faces is an array of objects
    if (!isEmpty(faces)) {
      setModelFaces({ faces });
      faces.map((face, i) => {
        const { topLeft, bottomRight } = face;
        const boxes = tf.concat([topLeft, bottomRight]).reshape([-1, 4]);
        const width =
          (bottomRight.dataSync()[0] - topLeft.dataSync()[0]) * scale.width;
        const height =
          (bottomRight.dataSync()[1] - topLeft.dataSync()[1]) * scale.height;
        const crop = tf.image.cropAndResize(
          tensorReshaped,
          boxes,
          [0],
          [height, width]
        );
        console.log(crop);
      });
    }
```

Boxes

```
Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {},
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 63582,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "2",
  "scopeId": 119566,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    4,
  ],
  "size": 4,
  "strides": Array [
    4,
  ],
}
```

Comment: Is it `cropAndResize` that is throwing the error ?

Comment: Does not mention it the error code is really long 
Failed to compile fragment shader.
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl/dist/tf-backend-webgl.node.js:388:8 in createFragmentShader
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl/dist/tf-backend-webgl.node.js:3844:8 in GPGPUContext.prototype.createProgram

Comment: Could it have something to do with the tensor shape? Tensor before being reshaped is [224,224,3] then I reshaped it into [1,224,224,3] to be passed into tf.cropAndResize()

Comment: What is the value of boxes ?

Comment: Boxes: 
Float32Array [
  69.20056915283203,
  111.86861419677734,
  110.365478515625,
  153.0338134765625,
]

Comment: You need to find which part of the code is throwing the error since the error message you output is not explicit. You can comment part of the code until you find which one is leading to the error

Comment: It is coming from crop. I have no issue getting the values of crop, width and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221551/discussion-between-yura-and-edkeveked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is coming from width and height that are scaled leading to float values. width and height are used for the shape of the crop tensor and should therefore be integers. You can either use `Math.Round` or `Math.floor` to get an integer value